# c++11 insert a vector into a particular position

Tags: c++

I am using c++11, I like to insert a vector into a particular position of another vector, here is a simplified code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3}; 

    vector<int> v2 = {0, 3, 9}; 

    vector<int>::iterator itr = find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 3); 
    itr = v2.erase(itr);

    // like to insert "3", "2" and "1" to the same position which ends up "1", "2" and "3"
    for (auto ri = v1.rbegin(); ri != v1.rend(); ++ri) {
        v2.insert(itr, *ri);
    }   

    for (const auto &i : v2) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }   
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code crashes.

Yes, I know some other STL API like transform() or copy() might be the one to use, but just wonder what is wrong of the above code?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/ Note how the insert(...) function is overloaded-- you can most definitely turn this into a one-liner with the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code crashes because `itr` is invalidated when `insert()` reallocates `v2` after it exceeds its max capacity.

Change the following:

```
v2.insert(itr, *ri);
```

to

```
itr = v2.insert(itr, *ri);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this API

`template <class InputIterator>
    void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`

So in your case, replace the second loop with:

`insert(itr,v2.begin(),v2.end())`

Comment: @TonyD No, it will become reversed as `0 3 2 1 9`.

Answer (score 2):

> what is wrong of the above code?

The iterator `itr` became invalid after `insert`, so program crashed at the 2nd execution of the for loop. You can use the return value of `insert` (iterator pointing to the inserted value) to get a valid iterator for insert position.

Change

```
v2.insert(itr, *ri);
```

to

```
itr = v2.insert(itr, *ri);
```

`insert` causes reallocation if the new size() is greater than the old capacity(). If the new size() is greater than capacity(), all iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise, only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

PS: Please see @Kam's answer, it's a better solution than hand-written loops in general cases.